# Automatically populate a column based on the column header name

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2013

I've been having lots of trouble trying to change my excel macro to do what I want it to. I have a worksheet (called User Sheet) whose 70th column (BR) gets automatically filled based on a column in another workbook. I need to change my macro so that it will populate this column based on it's header name rather than it's column index. The primary key column that it uses to match rows between worksheets must also be based on it's column name instead of it's column index. The reason for this is because the people who use this sheet will likely be adding and moving columns around, so doing it based on column indexes won't work.

Right now, the primary key column is in column B. The header rows are on row 2, not row 1. srcReturnCol is the column in the other worksheet with the data that the User Sheet column gets filled with. srcIdCol is the primary key column in the other worksheet. r, c, user_ran, and id are also all set as ranges.

I have tried to mimic what I have for finding the names of the return and primary key columns in the reference worksheet but nothing I've tried has worked. Any help on this I would be VERY thankful of!

```
..............


    LR = user_sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set user_ran = user_sheet.Range("BR3:BR" & LR)

    For Each c In user_ran.Cells

        id = c.EntireRow.Cells(3).Value

        If Len(id) > 0 Then

            r = Application.Match(id, srcIdCol, 0)

            If Not IsError(r) Then
                c.Value = Application.Index(srcReturnCol, r, 1)
            Else
                c.Value = "ITEM NOT FOUND"
            End If
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

---

```
Set g = user_sheet.Rows(2).Find(what:="Primary Key", _
                                lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)

    If Not g Is Nothing Then
        Set userReturnCol = g.EntireColumn
    End If

    Set g = Nothing
    Set g = user_sheet.Rows(2).Find(what:="Return Value", _
                                lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)

    If Not g Is Nothing Then
        Set userIdcol = g.EntireColumn
    End If

    LR = user_sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, userIdCol).End(xlUp).Row
    Set user_ran = user_sheet.Range(userReturnCol)

    For Each c In user_ran.Cells

        id = c.EntireRow.Cells(3).Value

        If Len(id) > 0 Then

            r = Application.Match(id, srcIdCol, 0)

            If Not IsError(r) Then
                c.Value = Application.Index(srcReturnCol, r, 1)
            Else
                c.Value = "PROJECT NOT FOUND"
            End If
        End If
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Why don't you use `Find` method of the `Range` object?

Comment: martin - I had tried doing something along those lines, which is shown above in my edit. I just can't get it to work no matter how much I play around with the code

Answer (score 0):

You can try using this somewhat clunky function to get the column of a matched string

Details:

```
i = Get_Col(worksheet.name, sStringToFind) ' by default will return the column
```

you can set a third parameter to true or 1 to retrieve the row instead.

By default it uses an approximate match where it trims all leading and trailing spaces from both the search string and the comparison string and it makes them both uppercase when comparing.

If you want an exact match set the 5th parameter to true.

```
i = Get_Col(worksheet.name, sStringToFind, False, True, True)
```

### Get_Col Parameters

1. Worksheet Name AS string
2. String To Find within worksheet AS string
3. bGetRow AS boolean - if you want to return the row number instead - by default is false
4. bGetCol AS boolean - by default is true
5. bExact AS boolean - by default is false - make true if you want to pull an exact match.

```
Function Get_Col(sWS As String, sFind As String, Optional bGetRow As Boolean = False, Optional bGetCol As Boolean = True, Optional bExact As Boolean = False) As Integer
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim r As Long, c As Integer
    Dim t As String

    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set ws = wb.Sheets(sWS)

    On Error GoTo Finish
    With ws
        Do
            r = r + 1
            For c = 1 To 16384
                t = .Cells(r, c)
                If bExact Then
                    If t = sFind Then
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                Else
                    If UCase(Trim(t)) = UCase(Trim(sFind)) Then
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                End If
            Next c
        Loop
    End With

Finish:
    If Err.Number = 0 Then
        If bGetRow Then
            Get_Col = r
        ElseIf bGetCol Then
            Get_Col = c
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Utilize like this:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim sWS As String
    Dim sPK As String, sOther As String
    Dim iColPK As Integer, iColOther As Integer
    Dim iRowPK As Long, iRowOther As Long

    sWS = "Sheet3"
    sPK = "Primarily the Key"
    sOther = "The Other Column"

    iColPK = Get_Col(sWS, sPK)
    iRowPK = Get_Col(sWS, sPK, True)

    iColOther = Get_Col(sWS, sOther)
    iRowOther = Get_Col(sWS, sOther, True)

    Debug.Print "PK: Cell(" & iRowPK & ", " & iColPK & ")"
    Debug.Print "Other: Cell(" & iRowOther & ", " & iColOther & ")"
    ' PK: Cell(10, 8)
    ' Other: Cell(18, 12)
End Sub
```

To set an example of how to implement with your second piece of code above:

```
Sub Help2()
    'Set g = user_sheet.Rows(2).Find(what:="Primary Key", _
    '                           lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
    g = Get_Col(user_sheet.Name, "Primary Key") '**************** INSERT THIS CODE

    If Not g Is Nothing Then
        Set userReturnCol = g.EntireColumn
    End If

    Set g = Nothing
    'Set g = user_sheet.Rows(2).Find(what:="Return Value", _
    '                            lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues)
    g = Get_Col(user_sheet.Name, "Return Value") '**************** INSERT THIS CODE

    If Not g Is Nothing Then
        Set userIdCol = g.EntireColumn
    End If

    LR = user_sheet.Cells(Rows.Count, userIdCol).End(xlUp).Row
    Set user_ran = user_sheet.Range(userReturnCol)

    For Each c In user_ran.Cells

        ID = c.EntireRow.Cells(3).Value
        If Len(ID) > 0 Then
            r = Application.Match(ID, srcIdCol, 0)

            If Not IsError(r) Then
                c.Value = Application.Index(srcReturnCol, r, 1)
            Else
                c.Value = "PROJECT NOT FOUND"
            End If
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```